# MySQL datetime error when trying to insert value into table

Tags: mysql

I get the following error when I try to insert the datetime value in a timestamp field in my MySQL table. I am trying to do this by running a Python code.

```
 _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-26 10:59:27+00:00' for column 'timestamp' at row 1")
```

Is there a workaround or a solution to this error ?

Comment: what is the code??

Comment: As far as I can tell MySQL doesn’t take the time zone in timestamp so that might be the issue?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Okay I will change the column name then.. thanks

Comment: @AkshayRohilla I have written a python code to insert log data from aws cloud trail to a mysql table. The python part is alright. The issue is in Mysql side. Hence I posted the mysql error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2018-03-26 10:59:27+00:00

This is a valid iso-8601 datetime value, but it is not a valid MySQL datetime literal. On that point, the developer is incorrect.

The documentation explains what ALLOW_INVALID_DATES does:

```
Check only that the month is in the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31.
```

In other words, 2018-03-26 would be a permissible date if allow_invalid_dates is set. This option does not do anything when the date or datetime isn't even in a valid format for MySQL.

The +00:00 is the timezone offset from UTC. In this case, the time expressed is in UTC, so the offset is zero hours, zero minutes.

Your workaround would be to remove the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from the sql_mode that is a default in the config file created during the MySQL 5.6 installation process... you need to carefully consider the implications of changing this, but it does allow the data to go in.

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into datetimetest(dt) values ('2018-03-26 10:59:27+00:00');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-26 10:59:27+00:00' for column 'dt' at row 1
```

-- remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES -- note that executing this only removes it for your
-- current session -- it does not make a server-wide config change

```
mysql> set @@sql_mode='no_engine_substitution';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- now MySQL will accept the invalid value, with a warning

```
mysql> insert into datetimetest(dt) values ('2018-03-26 10:59:27+00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'dt' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- the value did get inserted, but the time zone information was lost:

```
mysql> select * from datetimetest;
+----+---------------------+
| id | dt                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2013-08-26 12:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: "remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES -- note that executing this only removes it for your -- current session -- it does not make a server-wide config change" `set @@sql_mode='no_engine_substitution';` also remove anny other sql_modes better would be to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', '')` this will keep other sql_modes enabled because there can be more then two sql_modes enabled... But disabling `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` on the current session is pretty dangerous like you said.